# Show $\frac{(b+c)^2}{bc}l_a^2+\frac{(c+a)^2}{ca}l_b^2+\frac{(a+b)^2}{ab}l_c^2=4p^2$

Tags: geometry, triangles

Show that the equality $$\dfrac{(b+c)^2}{bc}l_a^2+\dfrac{(c+a)^2}{ca}l_b^2+\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{ab}l_c^2=4p^2$$ holds for a $\triangle ABC$ with sides $AB=c,BC=a, AC=b$, semi-perimeter $p$ and angle bisectors $l_a,l_b$ and $l_c$.
[image]

I am a little confused because I have recently seen so many angle bisector formulas. Here we can probably use that $$l_a=\dfrac{2}{b+c}\sqrt{bcp(p-a)}$$ and $$l_b=\dfrac{2}{a+c}\sqrt{acp(p-b)}$$ and $$l_c=\dfrac{2}{a+b}\sqrt{abp(p-c)}.$$ Can you show me? I don't think I can remember these formulas. What can I do if I forget them and can't check because I am not allowed to? What if we don't have them?

Comment: you are almost there- just replace the bisectors with the formulaes you have.

Comment: @dezdichado, thank you for the response! Are they well-known?

Comment: You can derive the formulas yourself if you are afraid of forgetting, deriving results by hand on our own helps in remembering them as well, clears our concepts and removes the fear of "forgetting them".

Comment: Stewart's Theorem is the best way to derive or remember lengths of cevians. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard angle bisector formula is $$l_a = \frac{2bc \cos\left(\dfrac{A}{2}\right)}{b + c}$$ which, using $\cos\left(\dfrac{A}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\dfrac{p(p - a)}{bc}}$, transforms to $$l_a = \frac{2\sqrt{bcp(p - a)}}{b + c}$$

Now putting these formulas into the LHS, $$ \sum \frac{(b+c)^2}{bc} \left( \frac{2\sqrt{bcp(p - a)}}{b + c} \right)^2 = \sum 4 p(p-a) = 4p \left( \sum (p - a) \right) = 4p^2$$

Hence proved :)